# PySerial and Inappropriate ioctl for device

Tags: python, linux, barcode-scanner, pyserial

i have been trying to control Keyence BL-1301 code scanner with N-UB converter (USB converter for this type of scanner).

I am using pyserial for this (port and others settings are correct):

```
serial.Serial(
    port     = '/dev/bus/usb/001/003',
    baudrate = 9600,
    parity   = serial.PARITY_NONE,
    stopbits = serial.STOPBITS_ONE,
    bytesize = serial.EIGHTBITS,
    writeTimeout = 0,
    timeout = 30,
    rtscts=True )
```

But. python gives me: *Could not configure port: (25, 'Inappropriate ioctl for device')*

Also, i have tried official driver for the windows and it works.
I need linux (Ubuntu) suppert for this device.

Any idea??
Thanks Mike

Comment: Your `port` looks unusual, should it not something like `/Dev/ttyUSBx`? Check the Logs.

Comment: `/dev/bus/usb/001/003` is related to USB bus, not to USB-serial device. Execute `ls /dev/ttyUSB*` to find your device.

Comment: I do not have anything like /dev/ttyUSB https://ctrlv.cz/shots/2017/08/02/oWi4.png and in dmesh is https://ctrlv.cz/shots/2017/08/02/Cht2.png

Comment: I figured out that in the usb device is cp2102 chip which changed VID and PID. Due to this VID and PID kernel do not know that should use cp210x.ko driver. Is any method to assign the device and driver??

Comment: I have the same problem with a USB printer that is on /dev/usb/lp1 and the result is the same